# Flutter google_maps_flutter package blocking alertDialog

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I am currently using the google_maps_flutter package, and I am placing it within a stack and overlaying it with a button. When the button is pressed, an alert should pop up.

The problem I am currently having is that it works upon first load, but if I exit the app, putting it in the background, and I reenter the app, the alertDialog is no longer showing up. It exists on the screen because I am unable to move the map, and I have to click the area where the button would normally be, but it is not visible.

Any ideas on what's going on?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: new Opacity(
                opacity: opacity,
                child: new GoogleMap(
                  onMapCreated: initializeMap,
                  options: GoogleMapOptions(
                    //trackCameraPosition: true,
                    compassEnabled: true,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Align(
              alignment: new Alignment(0, 1),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  alert();
                },
                child: new Image.asset(
                  'assets/test.png',
                  height: 150.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  }

alert() {
    return showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: new Text("hello"),
            content: new Text("hello"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                isDefaultAction: true,
                child: Text("Ok"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: Text("Cancel"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind `google_maps_flutter` is a developer preview at version 0.0.3.  Give it some time!